# Backbone collection not has no such method has each

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

I have a backbone collection that fetch some data but when I try to iterate over the collection using the each method it get

```
Object [object Array] has no method 'each'
```

Here is the model for the collection:

```
define (['backbone'],function(Backbone){
    return Backbone.Model.extend({
        url:'http://some_url/api/post/',
   });
});//end define
```

The collection itself:
'

```
   define (['backbone','models/Post'],function(Backbone,Post){
return Backbone.Collection.extend ({
    model: Post,

    initialize: function (model)
    {
        this.userId = model.userId;
        this.start = model.start;
    },

    url: function ()
    {
        return "http://some_url.com/api/post?userid=" + this.userId + "&start=" + this.start;
    },

    parse: function (response)
    {
        return response;
    }

    });
  });
```

This is the call to instantiate the view that uses the collection:

```
cookieVal = document.cookie.split ("; ");
                posts = new PostCol ({userId:id =   cookieVal[0].split('=')[1],start:1});

                posts.fetch ().success (function (response){
                    post = new Post({collection:response});
                    post.render();
                    console.log (post.el);
                });
```

And the implementation of the view that uses the collection:

```
 define (['jquery','underscore','backbone','views/Actor'],function($,_,Backbone,Actor){
return Backbone.View.extend ({
    className:'moment mb30',

    render: function ()
    {
        console.log (this.collection);
        this.collection.each (function (model){
            actor = new Actor ({model:model});
            this.$el.append (actor.render().el);
        },this);
        return this;
    }
});
});
```

Why is the each method not working and how can I solve this problem.

Comment: What does the line `console.log (this.collection);` print? Did you assign `this.collection` a `Backone.Collection`?

Comment: It prints [Object, Object, Object, Object]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a more idiomatic way to do this which may fix your bug as well, although your code is a bit odd, I didn't see a specific bug with it.

```
 posts = new PostCol({userId:id =   cookieVal[0].split('=')[1],start:1});
 post = new Post({collection:posts});
 posts.on('reset', post.render.bind(post)); //This should really go in PostView initialize
 posts.fetch();
```

Comment: It ensures that when the `reset` fires and `render` is called, it is invoked with the view instance bound to `this`.

Answer (score -1):

There is no such method `each()`. Do you mean `forEach()`? You need to have included `underscore.js` in your page for Backbone to use iteration functions.

Comment: Yes, backbone collections implement all of the underscore methods directly. http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-115